# config error: why sendmail concatenates domains?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, dns, sendmail

trying send mail via sendmail forward to cf16r@wp.pl, my domain is dorotamama.eu. and I get following:

> May  6 17:55:47 myubuntu sm-mta[3856]: r46FrhNl003854: to=cf16r@wp.pl,
>   delay=00:02:03, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=91761,
>   relay=wp.pl.dorotamama.eu. [89.75.41.50], dsn=5.3.5, stat=Local
>   configuration error May  6 17:55:47 myubuntu sm-mta[3856]:
>   r46FrhNl003854: r46FtlNl003856: DSN: Local configuration error May  6
>   17:55:48 myubuntu sm-mta[3856]: r46FtlNl003856: to=,
>   delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=60000,
>   relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [173.194.70.27], dsn=2.0.0,
>   stat=Sent (OK 1367855748 i8si29208219eem.229 - gsmtp) May  6 17:55:48
>   myubuntu sm-mta[3856]: r46FtlNl003856: to=root, delay=00:00:01,
>   xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=60000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent

gmail No PROBLEM, wp.pl PROBLEM. additionally here from mail.err:

> May  6 17:55:47 myubuntu sm-mta[3856]: r46FrhNl003854: SYSERR(root):
>   wp.pl.dorotamama.eu. config error: mail loops back to me (MX
>   problem?)

so I tried `cf16r@wp.pl` (it is correct address) but it concatenates to be: `cf16r@wp.pl.dorotamama.eu.` ?????????

**why?** other domain are working OK. (at least few that I checked till this moment)

DEBUG:

> echo '3,0 cf16r@wp.pl' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -bt -d8.20
>   dns_getcanonname(myubuntu, trymx=1)
>
> dns_getcanonname: trying myubuntu.chello.pl (AAAA)    NO: errno=0,
>   h_errno=1
>
> dns_getcanonname: trying myubuntu.dorotamama.eu (AAAA)    NO: errno=0,
>   h_errno=4
>
> dns_getcanonname: trying myubuntu.dorotamama.eu (A)   YES
>
> dns_getcanonname: myubuntu.dorotamama.eu
>
> _res.options = 812c3, HasWildcardMX = 0
>
> ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
>
> Enter ruleset address
>
> > canonify           input: cf16r @ wp . pl
>
> Canonify2          input: cf16r < @ wp . pl >
>
> dns_getcanonname(wp.pl, trymx=1)
>
> dns_getcanonname: trying wp.pl. (AAAA)
>
> NO: errno=110, h_errno=2
>
> dns_getcanonname: trying wp.pl. (A)
>
> NO: errno=110, h_errno=2 dns_getcanonname: trying wp.pl. (MX)
>
> NO: errno=110, h_errno=2 dns_getcanonname: trying wp.pl.chello.pl
>   (AAAA)
>
> NO: errno=0, h_errno=1 dns_getcanonname: trying wp.pl.dorotamama.eu
>   (AAAA)
>
> NO: errno=0, h_errno=4 dns_getcanonname: trying wp.pl.dorotamama.eu
>   (A)
>
> YES
>
> dns_getcanonname: wp.pl.dorotamama.eu
>
> Canonify2        returns: cf16r < @ wp . pl . dorotamama . eu . >
>
> canonify         returns: cf16r < @ wp . pl . dorotamama . eu . >
>
> parse              input: cf16r < @ wp . pl . dorotamama . eu . >
>
> Parse0             input: cf16r < @ wp . pl . dorotamama . eu . >
>
> Parse0           returns: cf16r < @ wp . pl . dorotamama . eu . >
>
> Parse1             input: cf16r < @ wp . pl . dorotamama . eu . >
>
> MailerToTriple     input: < > cf16r < @ wp . pl . dorotamama . eu . >
>
> MailerToTriple   returns: cf16r < @ wp . pl . dorotamama . eu . >
>
> Parse1           returns: $# esmtp $@ wp . pl . dorotamama . eu . $:
>   cf16r < @ wp . pl .  dorotamama . eu . > parse            returns: $#
>   esmtp $@ wp . pl . dorotamama . eu . $: cf16r < @ wp . pl . 
>   dorotamama . eu . >

### **so, does it means wp.pl wasn't resolved?**

additionally:

```
dig @192.168.1.1 fghj.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P2 <<>> @192.168.1.1 fghj.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

and +tcp:

```
dig @192.168.1.1 fghj.com +tcp
;; Connection to 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) for fghj.com failed: connection refused.
```

Comment: 1) Do you have any wildcard DNS records? [ `*.dorotamama.eu` ] 2) What is reported the following command executed by root? `echo '3,0 cf16r@wp.pl' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -bt -d8.20`

Comment: where do I have to search for this wildcard?

Comment: Could you post REAL domain name? On my host `nslookup -type=ns dorotamama.eu` returns NXDOMAIN (no such domain).

Comment: I have added these options to sendmail.mc because seen somewhere might help, but maybe this is actually source of problems? >>>  FEATURE(`always_add_domain')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`dorotamama.eu')dnl
FEATURE(`allmasquerade')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_entire_domain')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be solved by adding `WorkAroundBrokenAAAA` to sendmail's `ResolverOptions`.

1) Check your current resolver options

```
grep  ResolverOptions /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

2) Add the line below to your sendmail.mc and generate new sendmail.cf

```
define(`confBIND_OPTS',`WorkAroundBrokenAAAA')
```

3) Repeat the test

```
echo '3,0 cf16r@wp.pl' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -bt -d8.20
```

4) Check your new resolver options

```
grep  ResolverOptions /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

5) Restart sendmail daemon/service or make it reload configuration

Comment: thanks very much, but didn't help. I added this: define(`confBIND_OPTS',`WorkAroundBrokenAAAA')dnl to sendmail.mc, no change

Comment: What is reported by `grep ResolverOptions /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`? What is reported by `echo '3 cf16r@wp.pl' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -bt -d8.20`?

Comment: the same as before. Option is added, sendamil recompiled, deamon restarted. Still can't find and ends with wp.pl.mydomain.eu YES

Comment: grep ResolverOptions /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
O ResolverOptions=+WorkAroundBrokenAAAA

Comment: Ask your question at news:comp.mail.sendmail . include results produced by `echo '3 cf16r@wp.pl' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -bt -d8.20`

Comment: thank you very much, I will and will return here back with results if solution will be found.